# What is meant by WS-*?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

I have seen the abbreviation WS-*, but I have not been able to figure out what this means, and why is it important?

Comment: An illustration: [http://i.stack.imgur.com/twG3N.jpg](http://i.stack.imgur.com/twG3N.jpg).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

WS-* is shorthand for the the myriad of specifications that are used for web service messaging.

Some of the services are:

- WS-Security
- WS-SecureConversation
- WS-Federation
- WS-Authorization
- WS-Policy
- WS-Trust
- WS-Privacy
- WS-Test

There is a lot of information to digest, depending on what you need. [Here's a list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Web_service_specifications) of the specifications on Wikipedia.

Comment: While WS-* cover a lot of "enterprise" tick boxes they are rather complex, even with a software stack to help you interoperability is not easy in practice. Frequently known as "WS-Deathstar" for this reason. And because, for many purposes, the very simple REST route is enough (but doesn't tick those management boxes).

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand Richard's comment. Can someone bring that down a couple levels?

Comment: It's a snarky comment. WS* standards can be quite complicated to use for people that don't know them. The suggestion to use REST may work depending on your requirements - if you don't need security, strong typing, build in validation, sessions and so on. If you do, or you have a heavy investment in SOAP web services already then using these optional standards is the way to go

Comment: Its certainly the "way to go" if you're in some kind of "consultancy" - your project will magically take 9000 times longer, for fun and $$

Comment: MedicineMan, the WS-* stack has a reputation for being over-engineered and REST is a different web services option that works without the WS-* overhead. SOAP/WS-* and REST have different sweet spots and good reasons to use either, depending on context. As a gross over-generalization, REST is a great option for create, read, update, delete operations and WS-* is better for method-oriented services that need message security. Richard's complaint is that enterprises sometimes choose WS-* over REST because the stack offers complicated security features even though they won't need them.

Answer (score 5):

The Web Service stack.  There are a bunch of specifications for Web Services, and there names are written WS-whatever, for example: WS-SecurityPolicy.  The * is used as a wildcard to indicate that you are referring to the Web Services stack.

Answer (score 3):

That's the name of a set of standards related to web services by the W3C.

http://www.w3.org/2002/ws/

They're important because web services, by their very nature, need standards to interoperate between platforms.

Comment: Actually it's not just the W3c at all, there's also OASIS who look after most of the WS* standards; http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=wss

Answer (score 1):

WS-* refers to all the web service standards, eg WS-Security, WS-Addressing etc.

Wikipedia [has a list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Web_service_specifications).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the definition, `WS-*` also has some [implications](https://web.archive.org/web/20130325140509/http://hueniverse.com/2012/07/oauth-2-0-and-the-road-to-hell/):

> What 2.0 offers is a **blueprint** for an authorization protocol. As defined, it is largely useless and must be profiles into a working solution – and that is the enterprise way. **The WS-* way**. 2.0 provides a whole new frontier to sell consulting services and integration solutions.
>
> - Eran Hammer, former lead author of OAuth 2.0